# Why Apple's Metal Matrix Multiplication Example needs padding C

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, gpu

I'm learning Apple's [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) trying to do some GPU computation.

I checked the [matrix multiplication example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalPartialSumsCompute/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015013-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) given by Apple. There's a point I cannot understand.

In the file [MetalMatrixMult.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalPartialSumsCompute/Listings/MetalMatrixMultiplication_MetalMatrixMult_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015013-MetalMatrixMultiplication_MetalMatrixMult_h-DontLinkElementID_18)

```
// Number of rows in matrices A and C.
@property (nonatomic) uint16_t m;

// Number of columns in matrix A; number of rows in matrix B.
@property (nonatomic) uint16_t n;

// Number of columns in matrices B and C.
@property (nonatomic) uint16_t k;

// Output matrix (padded) C row count
@property (nonatomic, readonly) uint16_t M;

// Output matrix (padded) C column count
@property (nonatomic, readonly) uint16_t K;

// Output matrix C = A x B
@property (nonatomic, readonly) float* output;
```

It says the Matrix C is padded. I'm not clear what `pad` means here. Is it some kind of alignment? Cause I know there are types alignment in Metal's shader language specification, but I don't know why we need to pad a buffer herer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with optimizing memory access. Your GPU has a number of threadgroups, each containing a relatively small amount of dedicated memory (a few KB) that can be accessed very quickly. This is separate from your GPU's main memory, which might be a few GBs of comparatively slow memory.

Since it's unlikely that all 3 matrices (`A`, `B` and `C`) can fit into a single threadgroup's memory, and falling back to main memory inside loops would be extremely slow, we divide the computation into "blocks" or sectors.  Imagine dividing the result matrix `C` into a grid, where each sector is a collection of 8 x 8 elements:  we can then instruct Threadgroup 1 to compute the result for the top-left sector while other threadgroups compute the other sectors simulataneously.  In this case, Threadgroup 1 only needs the first 8 rows of `A` and the first 8 columns of `B` to compute its portion of `C`. This means we can send a much smaller amount of data to Threadgroup 1, keeping it well within the cache limit.

The reason Metal requires us to pad the matrices is so that it can divide `C` into a perfect grid. If your true result matrix is 12 x 18, and the sector size is 8 x 8, that means `C` is 1.5 x 2.25 sectors. The GPU can't efficiently operate on partial sectors, so you must pad your matrices with zeros to reach whole numbers - in this case 2 x 3 sectors or 16 x 24 elements. You sacrifice a little bit of storage and a few more clock cycles for highly optimized parallel processing.